# iOS 7 zooming is not working in ScrollView with AutoLayout but working in iOS8/9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have made a demo for zoom image using `UIScrollView`. My `ViewController` only contains one image.
The problem is the image cannot zoom in `iO7` (I have tested on `iPhone4S-iOS7`) but work perfectly in `iOS8`/`iOS9`.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentview;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        float minimumScale = [_contentview frame].size.width /[_scrollview frame].size.width;
        _scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 5;  //Change as per you need
        _scrollview.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;  //Change as you need
        _scrollview.zoomScale = minimumScale;
        _scrollview.delegate =self;
        _scrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.contentview;
}

@end
```

Here is the layout structure

[image]

**Screen.png** constraint
[image]
**ContentView** constraint
[image]
**ScrollView** constraint
[image]

**Here is my demo project**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B679aXO0SBmMeUVHTUdOcmxJSXM/view

Comment: Try to return image in viewForZoomingInScrollView

Comment: I tried to return image but it still not work

Comment: Well it is interesting now, can you share this demo project so that i could not have to create new one.

Comment: thank you, please wait a moment

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B679aXO0SBmMeUVHTUdOcmxJSXM/view here is the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103787/discussion-between-jageen-and-phan-vn-linh).

Comment: @Jageen , your solution (write 2 line code) make my image can zoom in iO7 but it the image look bad before zoom and the zoom is not beautiful. Do you have any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height and width `constraints` are causing this in iOS 7. A workaround would be, removing those `constraints` for iOS 7 and calculate `minimumScale` manually. in IOS 8 and above, do not change anything.

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float minimumScale = 1;

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) < NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_0) {
        [self.view removeConstraints:self.heightWidthConstraints];
        minimumScale = self.scrollview.frame.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.width;
    }

    _scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 5;  //Change as per you need
    _scrollview.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;  //Change as you need
    //_scrollview.zoomScale = minimumScale;
    _scrollview.delegate = self;
    //_scrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.scrollview setZoomScale:minimumScale animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Remove width and height contraint of `contentView`.
Add centralHorizontal constraint of `contentView` with `scrollView`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: i have recently checked your code, updated as per given step and tested and it working fine in ios 7 8 9

Comment: sorry for late respone. I try your suggestion but it still not work. can you share your code for me

Comment: check the image updated in answer. let me know if u got it

Comment: :(( I still not got it. I have all contraints like you

Comment: the image can zoom but only zoom in one direction(vertical) and can not zoom to horizontal

Comment: what exactly u expected ?

Comment: I want my image can zoom normally (for 2 direction horizontal and vertical). With your change, my image can only zoom to vertical (the height of image can change but the width not change)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103806/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-yagnesh-dobariya).